# li menu underline style will not go away

Tags: html, css

I created a menu with `ul` and `li` tags and have tried putting in the css `font-style:none` in all 3 sections, but was still not able to take out the underline from the menu.

```
<div class=menu>
    <ul>
        <a href="http://www.bettyzhangart.com"><img id=smalllog src="http://images2.webydo.com/31/313624/3958%2f7f54386b-c039-47a9-b2f5-eda78fc87287.png"/></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://bettyzhangart.com/about.html">BIO & CV</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://bettyzhangart.com/gallery.html">FINE ART</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://bettyzhangart.com/contact.html">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://bettyzhangart.blogspot.ca/" /a>BLOG</li>
        <li><a href=""/a>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
</div>

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    padding:50px 0px 30px 10px;
    display:inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
li a {
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: none;
    color: #8e8e8e;  
}
```

Comment: do you mean text-decoration:none? "underlie style" could refer to the normal default of a tags getting an underline on hover, or it could refer to whatever inherited style you gave it. Not sure. font-style is for things like oblique, normal, etc.

Comment: sweet that worked! Ugh I feel so stupid cause I've been using font-style this whole time.

Comment: How would I align the small logo image on the left to have the menu links be horizontally center aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since the comment worked I'll post it as an answer. to eliminate the normal underline of anchor tags on hover, you apply this:

```
a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

this is what worked for you. Since font-style is used for other things, like oblique, normal, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The underline is the value of the attribute text-decoration for "a" (the link tags, or anchors).

```
li a {
         ...your styles
         text-decoration: none;
     }
```

The available options are **none**, **underline**, **overline**, **line-through**, **inherit** (from parent) and some browsers support blink, which you should never use because it is annoying and was included as a joke.

Here's a list of the default styles for html4 tags - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html - these are the most used. Of course "a" is on there as :link but that's an answer for another question.

```
none | [ underline || overline || line-through || blink ] | inherit
```